# LINQ Query to insert data into the database

Tags: .net, linq

In my database, I have a table named Students, with 3 Columns (SNo, SName, Class).

I want to insert the value of only SName.

Can anybody tell me how to write the LINQ Query for this.

Thanks,
Bharath.

Answer (score 7):

Do you mean you want to *query* only the name? In which case:

```
var names = ctx.Students.Select(s=>s.Name);
```

or in query syntax:

```
var names = from s in ctx.Students
            select s.Name;
```

To *insert* you'd need to create a number of `Student` objects - set the names but not the other properties, and add them to the context (and submit it). LINQ is a *query* tool (hence the Q); insertions are currently object oriented.

Answer (score 6):

Are you using Linq-to-SQL ?  Do you want to insert a new record while only specifying the Name?

If so, this is roughly how it's done in C#.

```
using (StudentDataContext db = new StudentDataContext())
{
    Student newStudent = new Student();
    newStudent.SName = "Billy-Bob";
    db.Students.InsertOnSubmit(newStudent);
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thank you...
But, actually I want to insert only SName into the  Students table. The above query works fine for this.
Here, when we insert only the SName by using the above mentioned Quesry, what values did the table takes to the other two fields..SNo and Class ???
Please clarify me on this.
Thanks

Comment: SNo and Class will contain the default values for the database.  They will be the same as if you had manually added a new row in the database.

Comment: I think the 4th row of the code should actually be:
db.students.InsertOnSubmit(newStudent);

Comment: Thank You @Damien , I was new learner for LINQ and you answer helped me a lot